# Is this bad style to replace map or flatMap with return and get on Try in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm wondering if this is a bad code style to replace map with return and get on Try for readability? Say I have some variable with Try inside it and then I need to do anything on it.

```
val myData: Try[String]
```

I can do:

```
myData.flatMap{
 some long code
}
```

Or I can do:

```
if (myData.isFailure) return myData
val myString = myData.get
some long code that use myString
```

Comment: This is an opinion based question. I would suggest that if you need to extract a result from an underlying to, use either `getOrElse`, or pattern match: https://gist.github.com/YuvalItzchakov/292c2fb5e0a776a855158aef5c32fab3

Comment: Why are you telling this is option based question? I actually talking about Try. But yes, the same technique can be used with Option

Comment: Your question title is "Is it bad code to...". Bad code is subjective.

Comment: Yes. May be I should ask what better to use for functional style code

Comment: This is not an "option base question." It is an _opinion_ based question, which goes against SO guidelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes I would regard this as bad style. One of the biggest gains I have made as a programmer have come from replacing statements with expressions.  So I would rewrite your example using pattern matching.

```
myData match {
  case Success(myString) =>
    some long code that use myString
  case Failure(_) => tFileDf
}
```

I understand that if-guards are very common in languages like java and C# and they even make the code easier to read in these cases. Since moving to Scala I find less cases where if-guards would improve my code.  However the move to expressions has greatly improved the quality of all of my code.

Once you make this change you will gradually use less mutable state and side effects.  Gradually your methods will become pure functions.  They will probably become shorter. Then you will discover the benefits of total functions.  These things improve all of your code where if-guards are local optimisations that will start to clash with modern scala code, and even make it error prone to change.

In the case above I would probably consider exposing the `Try`, this exposes the  failure case more explicitly than returning a default or error value of the same return type.

Another reason that `return` is discouraged is that it does not alway play nicely in functions.

My advice is to embrace the more functional aspects of Scala and see where it takes you. It will take you more time to write than the equivalent in Java it pay dividends very quickly.